# Deck Coatings alternatives

Tags: wood, paint, deck

22 years ago I built a Weyerhaeuser outdoor wafer board topped deck. Frame is fir 4x10 outside frame with stringers 2x10 anchored to 10" lag screwed ledger boards on the house. Top coating is two coatings of liquid rubber Coat a Deck followed by four layers of latex paint. Carefully pressure washed 2 x annually most years. Eventually pin holes developed to rot out small sections. I want to rip off the lid, replace a few cupped stringers and install a new water proof walkable deck to ensure the large space under the deck remains dry for interminable rains in Eugene, Oregon. I see new coatings and new membrane products as well as new tiles and waterproof PVC products like Gorilla PVC that claim water proof decking. Any practicle experience alternatives that might last longer than 22 years?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not *sure* this is a shopping question (or at least the OP could [edit] it so it isn't).  "What could I build this wall out of?" would be on-topic and might have answers "brick, block, timber-frame, etc".  "What are the best sorts of bricks?" would be off topic.

Comment: @MartinBonner You're right; I should have suggested that. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin Bonner, I don't think a question like "what are the best sorts of bricks" would necessarily be off topic here, particularly if it was asked in relation to suitability/applicability. If asked like "what is the best *brand* of this sort of brick..." or "where can I *get* this sort of brick..." then yes: off topic.